# Transaction from vb.net to insert data into different SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, transactions

I have two SQL Server. I want to get data from the first one to the second and to update the first with value sent=1 there are not on the same area

What I want to do exactly is a transation in vb.net that can union all the query that will be applicated to the both db

Is it possible because if I put the query of the first db in a transaction and if i make if transaction = true  then execute the second truncation (that applicated to the second db) if I lost the connection that may because problem any one can help me to join all the querys on the same transaction

Answer (score 0):

In VB you would use the `TransactionScope` class to wrap your data access operations. It will create a local transaction to begin with and then promote it to a distributed transaction when required. The SQL Server Distributed Transaction Manager must be active for that to be possible, so that's something for you to read up on.

Comment: tnx a lot for ur help  i will try with it

Comment: i tried with transactionscope i have 2 connections the first one is succeful  when it's come to the second one an error appear for me error : MSDTC

Comment: "MSDTC" is not an error message.  What is the actual message?  That said, I did specifically state that you needed the Distributed Transaction Manager enabled. MSDTC is the Distributed Transaction Manager.  Did you read about it and learn how to configure it?

Comment: that exactly what i did last night but now i'm getting this error :interrupted transaction

Comment: And what did you find out when you searched the web for the specific error message in relation to the MSDTC?

Comment: they said that it s related to timeout but the error happen when u come to open connection  it doesn't take a  long time to show this error